# Not able to clear the goJS Diagram

Tags: angular, entity-relationship, gojs

I am showing an ER Diagram in a canvas with the help of goJS. What I want is to redraw the diagram based on the tables selected from the dropdown.

The new ER Diagram is getting drawn but I am not able to clear the old diagram.

I am getting the following error:

Invalid div id; div already has a Diagram associated with it.

What should I do in that case?

Answer (score 4):

Set the `diagram.div = null` to disassociate them.

> What I want is to redraw the diagram based on the tables selected from the dropdown.

Actually, you might want to just set a new `diagram.model` instead of deleting any Diagram. You only need to initialize the Diagram once.